# Having difficulty returning a value from an async function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to Node and have previously just written Javascript for simple browser extensions.  What I'm trying to do is run a shell script and then return the text for it on a get request (simplified version).

I've tried looking at callbacks and can't seem to get my head around it or even adapt another example to what I'm trying to do.  My main problem is either that the I'm receiving the error "first argument must be one of type string or buffer.  received type undefined" or "received type function" (when I tried to implement a callback, which is what I believe I need to do here?).

I've looked at a few examples of callbacks and promises and seeing them in abstraction (or other contexts) just isn't making sense to me so was hoping someone could help direct me in the right direction?

The code is very crude, but just trying to get some basic functionality before expanding it any further.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
const { exec } = require("child_process");

var ifcfg = function(callback) {
 exec("ifconfig", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
   console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
   return error;
  }

  if (stderr) {
   console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
   return err;
  } else {

   var output = stdout.toString();
   return callback(output);
  }
 });
}

app.get("/ifconfig", (req, res) => res.write(ifcfg(data)));


var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, a `callback` is a function passed into another function as an argument to be executed later.

Since the command is executed asynchronously you will want to use a callback to handle the return value once the command has finished executing:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
const { exec } = require("child_process");

function os_func() {
    this.execCommand = function(cmd, callback) {
        exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
                return;
            }

            callback(stdout);
        });
    }
}

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log("InsideGetss");
    var os = new os_func();
    os.execCommand('ifconfig', function (returnvalue) {
      res.end(returnvalue)
});

});
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply - I think that I may have missed something in the original code as when I tried to run your codeblock I now get "callback is not defined" but it does look similar to some of the examples I have seen online so I am unsure as to how the interpreter would like it to be declared..?

My main language is Python so am in uncharted territories when it comes to asynchronous programming

Comment: Just tried it now and that is exactly what I was aiming for, it makes more sense now too seeing how it should be written.  Looks like I wasn't too far from what I was trying but would've spent forever trying to figure that one out.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes. Infact I was wrong at first. But now I tested and worked fine. Cheers!